# Error running betar distriubtion in GAM mgcv

Tags: r, distribution, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to run a gam using the mgcv package with a response variable which is proportional data. The data is overdispered so initially I used a quasibinomial distribution. However because I'm using model selection that's not particularly useful as it does not produce AIC scores.

Instead I'm trying to use betar distribution, as I've read that it could be appropriate.

```
mRI_br <- bam(ri ~ SE_score + s(deg, k=7) + s(gs, k=7) + TL + species + sex + season + year + s(code, bs = 're') + s(station, bs = 're'), family=betar(), data=node_dat, na.action = "na.fail")
```

However I'm getting this warnings when I run the model.

```
Warning messages:
1: In estimate.theta(theta, family, y, mu, scale = scale1,  ... :
  step failure in theta estimation
```

And when I try and check the model summary I get this error.

```
> summary(mRI_br)
Error in chol.default(diag(p) + crossprod(S2 %*% t(R2))) : 
  the leading minor of order 62 is not positive definite
```

I would like to know:

1. What is causing these errors and warnings, and how can they be solved?
2. If not are there any other distributions that can be used with proportion data which enable me to subsequently use model selection techniques (such as the dredge function from the MuMIn package.

A copy of the dataset can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snia6tsjigdtf1e/node_dat.csv?dl=0)

Comment: As explained in `?betar`, the assumption is that data are in (0,1), i.e. 0 < x < 1. You response has mostly zeros, which may cause convergence problems.

Comment: Isn't this accounted for with the default eps argument? Or the large number of 0s still causes this issues? Is there a way of dealing with this correctly?